# Regex to replace certain characters on first line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm thinking that this is something very simple, but I can't find an answer anywhere online. I've found results on how to match the whole first line in a multiline string, but not how to find all occurrences of a certain character ONLY on the first line.

So for instance:

```
HelloX dXudXe
How areX yXou?
FxIXne?
```

Matching all **capital X**s only on the first line, and replacing that with nothing would result in:

```
Hello dude
How areX yXou?
FxIXne?
```

**This matches only the first X:**

```
/X/m
```

**This matches all Xs:**

```
/X/g
```

So I'm guessing the answer is the regex version of one of these statements:

```
"Replace all X characters until you find a newline"
"Replace all X characters in the first line"
```

This sounds like such a simple task, is it? And if so, how can it be done? I've spent hours looking for a solution, but I'm thinking that maybe I don't get the regex logic at all.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: As in programming language? JavaScript. But I was hoping for a general solution that works on any language that supports regex, without using any of the language specific functions. Just a simple regex 'statement' or pattern.

Comment: Regex is implemented differently in different languages.  Not all of them support look-arounds, for instance.

Comment: @James Different languages have different variations of regexp. For instance, a negative lookbehind would be the solution to this in many languages, but Javascript doesn't have it.

Comment: Did you read what I just said? Javascript does NOT support it.

Comment: So, this can't be done in a straightforward manner in JavaScript then?

Comment: Yep, we posted comments at around the same time. I read you.

Comment: @James It's very straightforward, just not with a single regexp replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the exact language you are using, it's difficult to give an example, but the theory is simple:

**If you have a complex task, break it down.**

In this case, you want to do something to the first line only. So, proceed in two steps:

1. Identify the first line
2. Perform an operation on it.

Using JavaScript as an example here, your code might look like:

```
var input =
    "HelloX dXudXe" + "\n" +
    "How areX yXou?" + "\n" +
    "FxIXne?";

var result = input.replace(/^.*/,function(m) {
    return m.replace(/X/g,'');
});
```

See how first I grab the first line, then I operate on it? This breaking down of problems is a great skill to learn ;)

Comment: How did you grab the first line? `input` contains all 3 lines because of the concatenation.

Comment: @Barmar `/^.*/` gets the first line.

Comment: I was just hoping for an even simpler solution. I'm very new to regex and I'm just starting to understand it, so I thought: "Hey, all languages must implement it the same, and there must be a very simple solution to this problem, that is applicable across all of them".  I guess not. I already had thought of something similar to this, but if there is not a single regex pattern for this in JavaScript, then that's okay. Thanks!

Comment: @James Trust me, with regex, the simplest solution is always to break it down and not try to do too much at once ;)

Comment: what about "all lines except the first one"

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into multiple lines, do the replacement on the first line, then rejoin them.

```
var lines = input.split('\n');
lines[0] = lines[0].replace(/X/g, '');
input = lines.join('\n');
```